# Creating isotop kind of grid grallery with jQuery.nnmGrid plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-isotope

I am trying to create a  isotop kind of grid view with jQuery.nnmGrid. But its not happening after a lot tries.

Basically I want this to be scrollable horizontal and adjust the height accordingly so that it wont cause to vertical scroll.

Thanks in advance.

Code and Jsfiddle URL:

```
jQuery( function( $ ) {

    var flag = false;
    var $container = $( '#container' ).nnmGrid();
    var $btn = $( '#resize-btn' )
        .on( 'click', function() {
            flag = !flag;
            $container.width( flag ? 470 : 630 );
            $container.nnmGrid( 'update' );
        } );
        console.log($('#container li').height());
        return false

} );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mufeedahmad/47sZz/13/

Comment: can we have any experts comments?? plzzzzzz I am still struggling with it